# How to use opencsv with my collection (list)?

Tags: java, grails, collections, groovy, csv

I need to parse 2 dimensional list, here is my schema list :

```
list (size=12) 
->[0] = "export.SampleJ:12432"  
   --> id = 12432  
   --> dateCreatedSample = "Tue Feb 03 19:04:23 CST 2009"  
   --> ttId = 0  
   --> chipId = 1012  
   --> ...  
->[1] = "export.SampleJ:12433"
   --> id = 12433
   --> ...
->[2] ...
```

I tried :

```
 List<String[]> allElements = list.readAll();
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(sw);
 writer.writeAll(allElements);
```

but I have this error : No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.readAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Also tried :

```
 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("MyFile.csv"));
 String[] entries = list;
 writer.writeNext(entries);
 writer.close();
```

I get a csv file, but with only : "export.SampleJ:12432", "export.SampleJ:12432", ...

How can I parse id, dateCreatedSample, etc ?

Is there a way to connect my list directly with opencsv ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a method to `SampleJ` to convert it into a `String[]`, e.g.

```
class SampleJ {
    // ...
    public String[] toStringArray =
        Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(getId()),
                      String.valueOf(getDateCreatedSample()),
                      String.valueOf(getTtId()),
                      String.valueOf(getChipId()));
}
```

then loop to write all lines, e.g.

```
for (SampleJ elem: list) {
    writer.writeNext(elem.toStringArray());
}
```